# Do posts/comments with the word "fakedemic" need to be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, code-of-conduct

I recently came across a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73745370/13376511) and I was unsure on what to do, if anything. Here's what the comment says:

> Thank you for the answer. Quick info: I was deeply interested in and inspired by Raku between August 2019 and February 2020, until the fakedemic aka Covid-19 kicked in at around March 2020. Actually the `@fib_v2` was written by me (at around November 2019) when I knew the fine detail of binding versus assigning a scalar variable to an array because I was frequently writing Raku code at the time. I intend to be fluent in Raku again.

So the comment isn't too useful in the first place, but I was surprised about the author's use of the word "fakedemic". The comment itself isn't primarily political, so there isn't much of a reason to flag it, but I still feel like it should be flagged or reacted to. What should I do?

I thought there'd be something on Stack Overflow's Code of Conduct, but I couldn't really find anything relevant to this type of stuff. Also, I'm not sure if it's even fair to flag/react to the comment because it could be seen as an opinion, albeit highly controversial. The only two flag reasons I think could be remotely applicable are no longer being relevant (because it's a thank you comment) and being offensive (however, again, highly opinion based).

Comment: I think even if the comment was useful, you could mod flag and ask for the irrelevant content to be removed.

Comment: I can't see being this enough of a problem to warrant anything other than flagging it as irrelevant and moving on.

Comment: [Another example of a weaved-in political message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419925/).

Comment: Given that whether COVID is a hoax or not has nothing to do with programming, I would just flag as no longer needed.

Answer (score 42):

Even if it didn't have any conspiratorial text, it doesn't add anything to the post.

It’s a conversational comment at best that’s essentially saying "thank you". The post author already responded to it; so it already served its purpose. I would flag it as "no longer needed".

Answer (score 28):

> The comment itself isn't primarily political, so there isn't much of a reason to flag it

It is not Stack Overflow's place to intervene in the political opinions of users anyway; but they do not belong in questions, answers, comments or chat. This is, after all, not a discussion forum, and topicality is taken very seriously. People can share their opinions on their user pages, or better yet on off-site blogs linked from their user pages. (Meta is inherently "political", but only with an extremely specific focus.)

The comment would be useless regardless of any political opinion expressed. It does not help understand the answer, and does not justify the need to ask the question (which does not require justification anyway). It was never needed, therefore it is "no longer needed" and should be flagged as such. The same is true of the response. The use of individual words or slogans for a political purpose is a red herring here - to *have the opportunity* to bring up real-world politics in discussing Stack Overflow content, one *necessarily has already* gone off topic.

Offensive comments, generally, are a subset of unnecessary comments - it should never be necessary to offend people in order to convey technical information, ask for clarification or rise on a point of order. (Well, there will always be people who take offense at being told that their question is not appropriate for the site; but that appropriateness is about as objective as it gets, so.) Flagging a comment this way entails a greater chance of moderators getting involved directly in order to reprimand someone's conduct. I don't see anything in the code of conduct about taking the political view implied here.

Comment: *"but they do not belong in  [...] chat"* ... I don't think that is true... you can discuss politics in chat if the room owners are fine with it and the discourse respects the code of conduct... Refer: *[If you're gonna talk Politics, you must respect those who disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289398/598066)*

Comment: I'm not really convinced that any meaningful policy consensus was reached (ironic, I know) in that Meta post.

Answer (score 19):

I think the idea that the COVID-19 pandemic is "fake" will be quite offensive to many people who have lost family members and friends to COVID-19, not to mention many other groups of people who have been affected by the pandemic in various ways. So I would flag such comments as "offensive".

Answer (score 13):

I say we take the situation a wee bit more seriously.

It so happened that this comment was more of an extended "thank you" comment and did not really provide any useful information; and comments in general are ephemeral and may be subject to removal in any case.

However, calling the COVID-19 pandemic a "fakedemic" **is not just a political opinion. It is a severe form of misinformation.**
And you might counter-argue that it is not the moderator's responsibility to fight against misinformation in the comments, but it can actually become a violation of the code of conduct, because it causes harm passively as people are desensitized to the problem and lead to infecting more vulnerable people. As such, it is also a form of *alienation* towards the people more concerned about avoiding infection.

Emphasis mine:

> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — **and those are just a few examples**. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, **don't use language that might offend or alienate**.

It is good that the comment is removed as soon as possible. This comment in particular is also a bit subtle and hard to distinguish from plain trolling or jesting about the people who underestimate the whole situation. But in the event that any user:

- reveals their colors as being against the use, *especially by other people*, of respiratory protection masks, ventilation, vaccines, and other confirmed safety measures;
- insists in using that term unironically to describe the COVID-19 pandemic;
- and proceeds to depict it in a way which is false and considered harmful (e.g "it does not exist", and "you're better off getting infected over protecting yourself")...

...do gather that as evidence and cast a post flag for moderator attention. Because at this point, the safety and wellbeing of participants and visitors are being jeopardized.

Comment: "...is not just a political opinion. It is a severe form of misinformation..." But that depends on what they meant by 'fakedemic' doesn't it? You've shoe-horned your own assumptions in. "Because at this point, the safety and wellbeing of participants and visitors are being jeopardized." By a single word in a comment? How is that jeopardizing anybody's safety, especially since we don't actually know what they truly meant by it? And safety from what exactly? You think the use of that word is going to change somebody's mind at this point? Most people, businesses and governments are moving on....

Comment: *"because it causes harm passively as people are desensitized to the problem and lead to infecting more vulnerable people."* I mean, I agree with you, but I'm very reluctant to take such an expansive interpretation of the Code of Conduct. I think that is not a good precedent to set.

Comment: "is not just a political opinion. It is a severe form of misinformation" To be misinformation, it would first have to be an objective claim, and would also have to represent itself as in some way authoritative (as opposed to, say, attempting to argue for a position from first principles).

Comment: We have a good place on the Internet here. YouTube comments are completely overrun by such conspiracy rubbish, both by trolls and bots. Even to point where they respond to each others' "comments". Creators *can* block them (the only real effective measure), but they seldom do (for whatever reason).

Comment: @ouflak the point where our wellbeing is jeopardized is not the point where this single comment is posted, but the point where we have someone doing what I described in the bullet points. Looks like we're both fond of shoehorning.

Comment: I think the bottom line is that SO/SE needs to be a trustworthy source of information to maintain its position - the very reason why most people ask programming questions here and not on Reddit/Quora is because those sites give less trustworthy answers. In the spirit of that, conspiracy theories and the like have no place here, or else they might endanger the core product. SO the company have always been responsive in deleting reported "snake oil"/non-scientific medicine adverts, so I think they are aligned with the community in this case.

Comment: While I agree that the language in the comment was inappropriate for SO and offensive to many, I think its status as *misinformation* isn't salient to the issue. If I were to make a comment that is inappropriate and offensive, and even likely to cause harm, but unambiguously true (leaking state secrets, perhaps?), the proper response would be the same. Let's not invoke "misinformation" as the reason for moderator action.

Comment: @trent _"Let's not invoke "misinformation" as the reason for moderator action."_ That I did not say, and I explained that this is a problem explicitly because it causes harm. Maybe the answer could have been rephrased to show less emphasis on the misinformation part, but ultimately and in this case, it's the misinformation itself that can cause harm.

Comment: "calling the COVID-19 pandemic a "fakedemic" is not just a political opinion. It is a severe form of misinformation"


Labeling something you disagree with as "misinformation" suggests that you have the complete truth (TM) on a matter, which you do not. It is not the official government position (TM), true, but there are a great many scientists, doctors, and others who agree with this position, and whose voices are being silenced by the prevailing spirit of censorship.

Comment: *"...there are a great many scientists [and] doctors who agree with this position [that the COVID-19 pandemic is 'fake']..."* I don't know of any, there might well be a couple, but there certainly is not "a great many". That is a definite example of misinformation worthy of the term. Perhaps it would be a good [Skeptics.SE] question?

Comment: @therealrodk Deleting that comment of yours could help you evade further embarrassment.

Comment: The fact that you aren't aware of the number of COVID skeptics and dissenters is a disturbing result of the censorship that has prevailed for the past three years. These people have held conferences, put out press releases and videos, and even scientific papers. But I should be embarrassed for knowing this, and mentioning it is misinformation...

Comment: I mean... there's flat earth conferences, press releases, videos, and "scientific" papers... doesnt mean it's real.

Comment: @therealrodk The fact that I haven't had contact with such kind of skeptics is a sign that pseudoscience and other BS have successfully been rejected by most societies and scientific groups. You probably fell into a misinformation cesspit. I pity for you.

Comment: > A group of 17,000 physicians and medical scientists led by Dr. Robert Malone has issued a declaration affirming that “the [COVID] state of medical emergency must be lifted, scientific integrity restored, and crimes against humanity addressed... the Global Summit asserts its mission “to end this orchestrated crisis, which has been illegitimately imposed on the world..." [Source](https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/dr-robert-malone-leads-thousands-of-scientists-in-calling-for-a-total-end-to-orchestrated-covid-crisis/)

See "Twitter Files" re: censorship of these legitimate drs and scientists.

Comment: @therealrodk You're only digging yourself deeper into that hole. _"See Twitter Files"_ that is not a constructive and unbiased source of information. And that link is from a conservative far right press, also very biased and hard to take seriously. You'd better stop.

Answer (score 6):

Any reasonable person would find such a comment unnecessary, off topic, inflammatory, offensive, and obviously false. Comments like that have no place in respectful discourse and should be flagged whenever they're found.

Comment: (tongue-in-cheek) The problem with this standard is that flags are handled by moderators, not "reasonable people". I mean, have you *met* any of the moderators?

Comment: So should I flag for special moderator attention, or a default option?

Comment: @MichaelM Don't let the user interface or the special labels confuse you. *All* of the comment flags, regardless of type, mean one thing, and one thing only: "this comment adds no value and needs to be deleted". The category labels/breakdowns just help to aid users (when flagging) in understanding what broad types of comments add no value and therefore need to be deleted. I think it's pretty clear from *everyone* who participated here that the comment in question adds no value and should be removed, so flagging it is appropriate. When in doubt, "no longer needed" is a good choice.

Comment: The only time you would want to flag a comment for a custom reason is when the reason why that comment adds no value and needs to be deleted is non-obvious. For example, maybe a useful comment was accidentally posted twice. Then, you'd flag the second copy of it with a custom reason, explaining that it was posted twice. That way, when a mod looks at the flagged comment in isolation on the mod flag dashboard, they won't inadvertently decline your flag, not realizing that it is actually a repost. In this case, I don't see any reason to raise a custom flag; the comment's problems are obvious.

Comment: @CodyGray In this case, it's really all three of the standard flag reasons: it's no longer needed (because it wasn't relevant to the discussion). It's also deliberately (or at least knowingly) inflammatory and offensive, so it's Unfriendly or Unkind at a minimum. In my opinion at least, it's inflammatory enough to rise to the level of harassment/abuse.